# Spring Boot - difference between 'public', 'static', 'templates' and 'webapp' directories under 'resources'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

What is the difference between these directories and which should contain the index.html in order to be rendered automatically by Spring Boot localhost?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content. public and static are equivalent and are used for static resources served directly. templates is for... templates used to dynamically generate an HTML page. webapp is for nothing at all. If you don't want to read the docuentation (which is not a good idea), why not at least make experiments?